# How can I change datagridview table with combobox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try change datagridview table with combobox. But I can't change with parameters. How can I change database table?

```
public DataTable TableLoad()
    {
        DataSet AL2020DS = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter SQLDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand Cmd1;
        string Sql = "SELECT * FROM @value ORDER BY [Donanım Seri No] ASC";
        Cmd1 = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
        Cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", cbbox_llisteler.Text);
        SQLDA.SelectCommand = Cmd1;
        DataTable AL2020DT = new DataTable();
        SQLDA.Fill(AL2020DT);
        return AL2020DT;
    }

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = TableLoad();
    }
```

When I try this parameters command ı get this error : Must declare the table variable "@value"

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: 2008 is completely unsupported. That should matter to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Your @value is not interpolated. Either use `string.Format()` or if you are using C#6 then use the below syntax. Also, notice I have removed `ASC` as that's default and no need of mentioning it.

```
string Sql = $"SELECT * FROM {value} ORDER BY [Donanım Seri No]";
```

Again, in the below code line you are trying to pass table name as parameter which is not possible. You can only pass query parameter as parameter and not table/column name.

So essentially you would do like

```
    string Sql = $"SELECT * FROM {cbbox_llisteler.Text} ORDER BY [Donanım Seri No] ASC";
    Cmd1 = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);        
    SQLDA.SelectCommand = Cmd1;
```

Comment: What if he need to pass condition like where [Donanım Seri No] = @value. I think OP is looking to pass the value in where condition.

Comment: @SurajKumar I don't see that. You can't pass table name in `WHERE` clause I believe.

Comment: I am thinking like - Select * from tblSerialNo where [Donanım Seri No] = @value.

Comment: So how can I change table with out parameter?

Comment: When I try this code, I get this error: Incorrect syntax near '}'.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution

```
string Sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TextBox1.Text + " ORDER BY [Hardware Serial Number] ASC"
```

I use this code in click function.